# PDF Metadata using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, metadata

Is it possible to have the same PDF metadata that is generated from the PDFLaTeX work on XeLaTeX?

Whenever I have `pdfauthortitle`, `pdfcopyright` and `pdfpubtype` enabled during the XeLaTeX compile on VSCode on Windows, I get the error: `Undefined key 'pdfauthortitle'`.  However, these commands work on the PDFLaTeX compile.

How to get the same metadata to show up on the XeLaTeX compile?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={My title},
    pdfsubject={Machine Learning},
    pdfauthor={My author},
    %pdfauthortitle={\xmpquote{I am Halo\xmpcomma\ FIE}},
    %pdfcopyright={Copyright (C) 2023, My author},
    %pdfpubtype={Proposal},
    pdfkeywords={{Testing 1}, {Testing 2}},
    pdfproducer={XeLateX with hyperref},
  pdfcreator={Xelatex}]{hyperref}
}

\begin{document}
Contents of the document
\end{document}
```

Comment: uncomment the keys and try your example with pdflatex: they will error there too.

Comment: Well alrightee then...that was my faux pas...I will now remove this post!

Comment: they will work with hyperxmp, but you naturally must load it.